# Lazy Loading in gridview

Tags: android, json, gridview, imageview, lazy-loading

this is gridview that get image from json. I successfully with it. But when I get it from server it has a lot of images, that mean all images from server. I want to once load is 12 images.

How can I limit number of images to load?

Please help me briefly because I blind with lazy loading. If the code below not not enough. here is full source http://pastie.org/5583485

in this url, 50 is a number of image to load, i can limit number of image by this value whatever i want. but i just can load once time, so i can't load it more. this url provide image path as json.

```
String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/card/all/50/0/?token=57LzEsmBeykLbDCD04wTgK9WWV2XjJY0XBdqVU0HQvjIdu5EtTWOT1IQ1AYNwxt6Q5bG6FG73uvzLQSDGAIezwc8VcopEp0s63uzbdVgLSfts0TLmuVDOgyfn4lX";
```

doInBackground of asynctask

```
public class DownloadJSONFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url = "http://rest.mcolle.com/card/all/50/0/?token=57LzEsmBeykLbDCD04wTgK9WWV2XjJY0XBdqVU0HQvjIdu5EtTWOT1IQ1AYNwxt6Q5bG6FG73uvzLQSDGAIezwc8VcopEp0s63uzbdVgLSfts0TLmuVDOgyfn4lX";
        JSONArray data = null;

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getJSONUrl(url));

            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;
            data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Object
                map.put("cardimage", (String) c.getString("cardimage"));
                map.put("ImageThumBitmap",(Bitmap) loadBitmap(c.getString("cardimage")));

                map.put("categoryid", (String) c.getString("categoryid"));

                MyArrList.add(map);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        ShowAllContent(); // When Finish Show Content
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
        removeDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS);
    }
```

ImageAdpater where i show image

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myArrList) {
        context = c;
        MyArr = myArrList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return MyArr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        }
        viewHolder.categoryCard = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_card);

            viewHolder.categoryCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_etc);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        try {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) MyArr.get(position).get("ImageThumBitmap"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        }

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use universal image loader ,

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I saw it already but it isn't bring me better. can you place some code? like i describe above I blind with it. thanks and million thanks

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68130108/UniversalImageLoaderExample.rar  you can find an example that shows how you can use.